# Table Rate Shipping: Setting a minimum amount spend

Tags: shipping, table-rates

I'm setting up Table Rate Shipping for a client but they have one proviso and that's this method should not become available unless the order is at least $300 or more. I don't see a setting to turn this on. So is there a way to incorporate a minimum spend or would I have to go the extension route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set all of the shipping order subtotal conditions of your table rate shipping to be greater or equal than $300.

E.g. https://screencast.com/t/dOUFdhTL6iFw

Reference doc: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html

Comment: That’s what I have already done. I’m just concerned that orders $299 or lower could still trigger the shipping but it would be free. Which I don’t want.

Comment: No, the table rate shipping won't be shown if the order subtotal is $299 or lower. Isn't it working on your end? If it is not, can you send me the table rate CSV file?

Comment: I actually just completed the file (lots of zip / postal codes) and I tried to import it but I received the cryptic message "Something went wrong while importing table rates" with no further explanation as to why.

Where could I send you the file?

Comment: Never mind. I got it to import. I think it was some formatting in the spreadsheet that wouldn't allow me to import it.